# Count Date Occurances across Multiple Columns

Tags: ms-access-2007

I've created the following but it keeps coming up with the error message You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ICE Team' as part of an aggregate function.

```
SELECT ztSub.[Master Sheet].[ICE Team], ztSub.[date], Count(ztSub.[Count])
FROM (SELECT [Master Sheet].[ICE Team],[Master Sheet].[Visit Date (planned for)] AS [date],Count([Master Sheet]![Visit Date (planned for)]) AS [Count]
FROM [Master Sheet]
UNION
SELECT [Master Sheet].[ICE Team],[Master Sheet].[Date retasked to?] AS [date], Count ([Master Sheet]![Date retasked to?]) AS [Count]
FROM [Master Sheet] )  AS ztSub
GROUP BY ztSub.[Master Sheet].[ICE Team];
```

Comment: @A Hughes, it is always appreciated if you share what you already have and where (you think) the problem is at.

Answer (score 1):

This now works.  I incorporated a sum of the [Count of Dates] and its given me my results.

```
SELECT [Total].[Ice Team] AS [Ice Team], ztSub.Period, Sum(ztSub.[Count of Dates]) AS  [SumOfCount of Dates]
FROM (SELECT Total.[Ice Team], Total.[Re-Visited] AS Period, Count([Total]![Re-Visited]) AS [Count of Dates]
FROM Total
GROUP BY [Ice Team], [Re-Visited]
UNION SELECT Total.[Ice Team], Total.Visited AS Period, Count([Total]![Visited]) AS [Count of Dates]
FROM Total
GROUP BY [Ice Team], Visited)  AS ztSub
GROUP BY [Total].[Ice Team], ztSub.Period;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only result you are looking for is a list of dates and count of occurences, you might want to try a query with a union:

```
SELECT date, count(*)
FROM (
(SELECT date_col1 AS date
FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT date_col2 AS date
FROM table1) )
GROUP BY date
```

EDIT FOR UPDATED QUESTION:

Your error comes from the fact that you do the count in your inner queries but the group by on your outer query. If you look at one of your inner queries separately:

```
SELECT [Master Sheet].[ICE Team],[Master Sheet].[Visit Date (planned for)] AS [date],Count([Master Sheet]![Visit Date (planned for)]) AS [Count]
FROM [Master Sheet]
```

then we still get the same exact error. This is caused by the fact that you do a count of your dates in the select clause without specifying what to do with the [ICE Team] value. You might want to include a group by-clause for the [ICE Team] value. You already did for the outer query, but it should be done in this inner query too. Same goes for your `Visit Date (planned for)` value, otherwise you'll get the same error for that one.

Try this query, although I'm not sure it'll give the results as you want them too. (For that, you'd have to add a clear example of input and expected output to your question.)

```
SELECT ztSub.[Master Sheet].[ICE Team], ztSub.[date], Count(ztSub.[Count])
FROM (SELECT [Master Sheet].[ICE Team],[Master Sheet].[Visit Date (planned for)] AS [date],Count([Master Sheet]![Visit Date (planned for)]) AS [Count]
FROM [Master Sheet]
group by [ICE Team],[Visit Date (planned for)]
UNION
SELECT [Master Sheet].[ICE Team],[Master Sheet].[Date retasked to?] AS [date], Count ([Master Sheet]![Date retasked to?]) AS [Count]
FROM [Master Sheet]
group by [ICE Team], [Date retasked to?] )  AS ztSub
GROUP BY ztSub.[Master Sheet].[ICE Team],date;
```

Comment: This looks like what I need but I keep getting an error message in the join operation.

Comment: @AHughes I edited my answer to follow up on your edited question. Pls check if this helps and let me know. Also, to get a more clear picture of what your query is supposed to do, a sample of your [Master Sheet] table and the expected result for that would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I've made a slight change and its working fine -  see my answer above.